# creating an empty data frame and filling with existing column in another file with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create an empty data frame and filling the empty data frame with columns existing in another file. It works when i use this simple code.

```
InputData['Quote'] = store['QUOTE_ID']
```

but when i add some conditions before the code then it does not accept the conditions and gives same values as in store(original)file.
below is my code i am trying to use .

## original data set

```
InputData = pd.read_csv('datalink')
```

## creating empty data frame

```
 OutputData=pd.DataFrame()
```

## code with conditions

```
for i in xrange(len(InputData.index)):
  if (i % 5000) == 0:
      print i,
  if ((InputData.ix[i,'WIN']=='Y') and          ((InputData.ix[i,'COM_C']=='H') or (InputData.ix[i,'COM_C']=='S'))    and(InputData.ix[i,'COM_L']!=0)):
        OutputData['Quote']=InputData['QUOTE_ID']
        OutputData['ComList']=InputData['COM_LISTPR']
        OutputData['WIN']=1
        OutputData['COM_C']=InputData['COM_C']


 OutputData.to_csv(link,index=False)
```

## original data set

```
QUOTE_ID    WIN COM_C   COM_L
1400453-IT  N   H   1.46E+05
1400453-IT  N   H   7.12E+04
1400453-IT  N   H   2.74E+04
1403796-IT  Y   S   3.11E+04
1400453-IT  N   M   3.12E+02
1403796-IT  Y   H   3.97E+04
1403796-IT  Y   H   3.97E+04
1403796-IT  Y   M   1.99E+02
1403796-IT  Y   M   1.99E+02
1403796-IT  Y   H   7.40E+04
1403796-IT  Y   H   7.40E+04
1403796-IT  Y   M   3.19E+02
1403796-IT  Y   M   3.19E+02
1403796-IT  Y   H   9.56E+04
```

## expected data set

## require only Y from InputData and replace to 1 if Y

```
        Quote   WIN COM_C   COM_LISTPR
1403796-IT  1   S   3.11E+04
1403796-IT  1   H   3.97E+04
1403796-IT  1   H   3.97E+04
1403796-IT  1   H   7.40E+04
1403796-IT  1   H   7.40E+04
1403796-IT  1   H   9.56E+04
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Python code -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', delim_whitespace=True)  # reading file

modified_df = df[(df['WIN'] == 'Y') & ((df['COM_C'] == 'S') | (df['COM_C'] ==
                                                               'H')) &
                 (df['COM_L'] !=
                  0)].copy()

modified_df['WIN'] = 1

print(modified_df)
```

Output -

```
      QUOTE_ID  WIN COM_C  COM_L
3   1403796-IT    1     S  31100
5   1403796-IT    1     H  39700
6   1403796-IT    1     H  39700
9   1403796-IT    1     H  74000
10  1403796-IT    1     H  74000
13  1403796-IT    1     H  95600
```

Comment: I didn't know dataframe had a replace attribute, good to know. But there, since there are only 'Y' in the column 'WIN' you might as well use: modified_df['WIN'] = 1

Comment: I got a warning when I tried to do that - `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: Yes, because the way you defined modified_df, it's an image of df, not a whole new object. If you add .copy() when you first define modified_df, the warning won't appear anymore.